# Unity 2D/3D Drag a sprite over check points in a path

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to implement a concept in unity application where user should drag object following checkpoints in a give path. Sprite/Object should not go far away from the path. I have implemented [this concept](https://forum.unity.com/threads/move-gameobject-along-a-given-path.455195/). This is working fine when we auto move object with update function but when drags it is going any point.

1.) drag object in a sequence of checkpoints in a given path.

2.) restrict/fix sprite to give path while dragging

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, we are not here to program your game for you. Please provide the code you've tried and exactly where you are stuck and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Are you sure you want a code in `unityscript` which is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now ?

Comment: @aman for general technique questions like this, you may prefer the GameDev site

Comment: Guys at the same time, it's so easy to answer this question, maybe quicker to just do so!  Heh!

Answer (score 0):

Just make an animation (using Unity's fantastic animation system) where the object moves from 0.0 to 1.0 along the path (or any path you want).

When the mouse is down, simply convert the x value to 0->1 and set the animation.

It's that easy in Unity.